# one database or multiply

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a server with few websites there and its something like in the following picture.

I decided to add some more panel as a new website. Each website had its own structure but I did remove the unnecessary part so I'm just using one single database for all of the websites. Recently I had an issue with high CPU usage of MySQL. I'm not sure if it is because of using one single database or not.

[image: here is the picture I made from the websites I have in my server]

In addition: Is there a way to get data with cronjob less than one minute? I tried sleep() but I guess its not a good idea.

Comment: It should be no problem to run everything in one database. I would see how you can improve the efficiency of your MySql requests. If you want to run a cronjob more often than every minute, you should write your own small server with sleep(), which runs continuously and takes care of this. However, you should carefully consider if this is really useful if something very complex should be run so often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing one database amongst multiple applications has some serious disadvantages:

- The more applications use the same database, the more likely it is that you hit performance bottlenecks and that you can't easily scale the load as desired.
- Maintenance and development costs can increase: Development is harder if an application needs to use database structures that aren't suited for the task at hand but have to be used as they are already present. It's also likely that adjustments of one application will have side effects on other applications ("why is there such an unecessary trigger??!"/"We don't need that data anymore!"). It's already hard with one database for a single application, when the developers don't/can't know all the use-cases.
- Administration becomes harder: Which object belongs to which application? Chaos rising. Where do I have to look for my data? Which user is allowed to interact with which objects? What can I grant whom?

Coming back to your issue on high resource usage, this is ideally caused by multiple applications utilizing the same database which increases needed CPU utilization. I strongly suggest maintaining every application with its own database for increased performance and scaling capabilities.

Comment: if I use multiply databases I mean each database for each website all of them will have same data on few tables and its the data I'm getting from API, still its better to use multiply databases?

Comment: Yes as I explained above it will enable you to increase performance and improve scalability incase of any upgrades, this will reduce distortion. Also, it will reduce resource utilization on the server as you will not have  multiple requests from various websites on a single database.

Comment: I see! thank you, I will try to separate them and check the result. tnx again

Comment: Give it a try, and since your new, the proper way of saying thank you is accepting the answer or upvoting. Goodluck